# If $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$ , $N$ be invertible, then there is $y\in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that ${\left\| y \right\|_2} = 1$ and $x=Ny$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$ and $N\in M_n$ be invertible.

Is it true that:

there is $y\in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that ${\left\| y \right\|_2} = 1$ and $x=Ny$.

Comment: What if $x=0$?  Then $N^{-1}x=y$, then $\|y\|_2=x^TN^{-1}Nx=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=0$ is allowed, then $N^{-1}x=y$, then $\|y\|_2=x^TN^{-1}Nx=0$.  Which shows that no $y$ exists.

If $x=0$ is not allowed, then $\{x\}$ can be extended to a basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$.  Put the basis as the columns of $N$ and $y=e_1$.

Comment: Let $\left\{ {{x_1},{x_2},....,{x_n}} \right\}$ basis for $C^n$ and $x_i $ be columns of $N$, and $x = {\alpha _1}{x_1} + .... + {\alpha _n}{x_n}$ .If We put $y = {e_1}$, it is true that $x=Ny$? (Please more guide.)

Comment: The basis *extends* $\{x\}$, so $x=x_1$.